# C++ "fatal error LNK1120" unresolved static class members

Tags: c++, static, declaration

I get the following error message (someone feel free to edit the unnecessary bits):

> 1>FIXDecoder.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static class std::unordered_map,class std::allocator >,class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class
>   std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class
>   std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class
>   std::allocator > const ,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > > > >
>   FD::FixValueMappingsDict"
>   (?FixValueMappingsDict@FD@@0V?$unordered_map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@@std@@A)
>
> 1>FD.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static
>   class std::unordered_map,class std::allocator >,class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class
>   std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class
>   std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class
>   std::allocator > const ,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > > > >
>   FD::FIXFieldNoDict"
>   (?FIXFieldNoDict@FD@@0V?$unordered_map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@@std@@A)
>
> 1>C:\visual studio 2012\Projects\FD\x64\Debug\FD.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

for this code:

```
//FH.h
#ifndef FD_H
#define FD_H

#include "FM.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

class FD{
public:
    FD();
    FD(FM message);
    ~FD();
    FD(const FD& tocopy);
    FD& operator=(const FD& toassign);

private:
    static unordered_map<string,string> FIXFieldNoDict;
    static unordered_map<string,string> FixValueMappingsDict;
};

#endif

//FD.cpp
#include "FD.h"
#include "Mappings.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

FD::FD(){
    FIXFieldNoDict = Mappings::createFIXFieldNoDict();
    FixValueMappingsDict = Mappings::getFIXValuesDict();
}
```

Mappings.h just contains some functions which create an unordered_map

```
#ifndef MAPPINGS_H
#define MAPPINGS_H

#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Mappings{

public:
    Mappings();

    static unordered_map<string,string> createFIXFieldNoDict();

    static unordered_map<string,string> getFIXValuesDict();
.
.
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create instances of your static members in the FD.cpp file:

```
//FD.cpp
#include "FD.h"
#include "Mappings.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<string,string> FD::FIXFieldNoDict = Mappings::createFIXFieldNoDict();
unordered_map<string,string> FD::FixValueMappingsDict = Mappings::getFIXValuesDict();


FD::FD(){
}
```

Note that you shouldn't initialize them in the `FD` constructor, as you can use static members before construction of any object (and you need to initialize them once and not every time when some object is constructed).

Comment: Thanks for that! Knew it was something to do with static and translation units!

Answer (score 3):

You should implement this two members in FD.cpp file:

```
static unordered_map<string,string> FIXFieldNoDict;
static unordered_map<string,string> FixValueMappingsDict;
```

like that:

```
unordered_map<string,string> FD::FIXFieldNoDict;
unordered_map<string,string> FD::FixValueMappingsDict;
```